# Android Stuido wont open

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

Im trying open android studio but it gives me an error list and some of the errors about Intellij IDE. I can't understand how those both IDE's connected each other.

Here is the list of errors.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing '
                com.almightyalpaca.jetbrains.plugins.discord.plugin.development.DisableDynamicPluginComponent
            ' [Plugin: com.almightyalpaca.intellij.plugins.discord]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:571)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:382)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.access$registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.client.ClientAwareComponentManager.registerComponents(ClientAwareComponentManager.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$doInitApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$doInitApplication$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initApplication(ApplicationLoader.kt:61)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.kt:13)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$startApplication$7.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:298)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
                com.almightyalpaca.jetbrains.plugins.discord.plugin.development.DisableDynamicPluginComponent
             PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Discord Integration, id=com.almightyalpaca.intellij.plugins.discord, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins\plugin, version=1.6.1, package=null, isBundled=false), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=117, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:495)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:374)
    ... 22 more

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

I tried to upgrade JDK version and delete both of the IDE's and reinstalled it but it won't work it gives me this mistake all the time. Also I tried to visit the the websites that errors gives me but they dont open aswell

Comment: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA so that is how they are related. The error seems to come from a discord plugin. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: when i look at the plugins i don't see a discord plugin

Comment: I think 1 of your files got corrupted somehow. your best bet is to re-install the program

Comment: I did that like 10 times but it didn't work aswell

Comment: Check your user home directory and there the hidden appdata folder. In it's subfolder `roaming` and `local` you will find a Google and withing AndoridStudio directory. Delete it in both locations to reset your Android Studio installation.

Comment: Have you tried to clean "~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\plugins\" folder?